# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics - newApplication

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

### Issue

I am simply trying to convert a custom `AndroidJUnitRunner` class from Java to Kotlin.

### Code

**CustomTestRunner.java**

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws IllegalAccessException,
        ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp.class.getName(), context); 
    }
}
```

**CustomTestRunner.kt - (causes error - see stacktrace below)**

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "<>.CustomTestRunner"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0"
  androidTestCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0"
}
```

### Error

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 4948): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959): Process: <>.debug, PID: 4959
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at <>.newApplication(CustomTestRunner.kt)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4959):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 2870): Error in app <>.debug running instrumentation ComponentInfo{<>.debug.test/<>.CustomTestRunner}:
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @DMonkey Just to leave those classes in Java.

Comment: Trying downgrade the kotlin version in your `build.gradle` file, it work for me.

Answer (score -2):

You might missing classpath dependency:

```
buildscript {
    . . . 
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
    }
}
```